# Creat a list with repeated terms by adding a multiplier index in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

Given a dataframe like this:

```
row1 = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'AAA', 'AAA']
row2 = ['CCC', 'CCC', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA']
col = {'List': [row1, row2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(col)
```

which leads to:

|  | List |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ['AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'AAA', 'AAA'] |
| 1 | ['CCC', 'CCC', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA'] |

I would like to generate the following dataframe:

|  | List |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ['AAA', 'BBB x 2', 'CCC', 'AAA x 2'] |
| 1 | ['CCC x 2', 'BBB', 'AAA x 3'] |

where the final column **List** contains a multiplier index that indicates how many times the term appears consecutively in the list.

Could you suggest a pandas instruction that solves this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you may need to check with `explode` ,then we create the subgroup with `cumsum` ad `shift`

```
s = df.explode('List')
s = s.groupby([s.index,s['List'].shift().ne(s['List']).cumsum()])['List'].agg(['first','count'])
out = s['first'] +'x' + s['count'].astype(str)
out = out.mask(s['count']==1,s['first']).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
out
Out[202]: 
0    [AAA, BBBx2, CCC, AAAx2]
1         [CCCx2, BBB, AAAx3]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

itertools `groupby` can do what you need.  The custom function joins the count to the value if there is more than one record in that group.

```
from itertools import groupby
import pandas as pd

row1 = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'AAA', 'AAA']
row2 = ['CCC', 'CCC', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA']
col = {'Lists': [row1, row2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(col)

def count_items(row):
    output = []
    for k, d in groupby(row):
        x = list(d)
        if len(x)>1:
            output.append(' x '.join([k, str(len(x))]))
        else:
            output.append(k)
            
    return output

df['Lists'] = df.Lists.apply(lambda x: count_items(x))

print(df)
```

Output

```
                          Lists
0  [AAA, BBB x 2, CCC, AAA x 2]
1       [CCC x 2, BBB, AAA x 3]
```